# The sinister Clippycorn

Tags: support

Today, while digging through a bunch of questions, I've had a strange encounter with "Clippycorn" here:

[image: The Clippycorn]

Does anybody have any idea what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Welcome to April Fools, StackExchange style. That's my guess, anyway.

Comment: Ah, did not realize it was past midnight already.

Comment: It isn't yet, but I'm betting they did the push early just because.

Comment: or perhaps there are different timezones in the world :)

Comment: No, this is a completely legitimate new feature. Obviously.

Comment: [More details.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127701/how-can-i-get-the-april-fools-joke-to-appear)

Comment: Thanks guys. I was really scared and had some bad nightmares of this critter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sever Fault, and all the Stack Exchange sites, operate on UTC time; where it is already April 1st.

Comment: This has nothing to with UTC; it's the user's time zone that counts. Also, this is a very boring answer ;)

Comment: @balpha Thanks for the consistency; really makes it easy for users and moderators to figure out what's going on... I'm a SysAdmin, we're boring, predictable, steady, and reliable; if not slightly curmudgeonly and tamped.